# Make a background transparent in Tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, background

while developing my app I finally succeeded in making everything I want to, the latest being attaching a background image to the app window. My only issue now is with the background of the labels, they are covering the background making the app ugly.
I tried using:

```
window.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor',color)
```

but something weird happened, the whole thing became transparent and It's not my desired outcome as you can see :
[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eujbx.png)
anyone knows how to get around this or how to fix it?
been looking everywhere but can't really find a solution to my issue

Comment: There's no way to do that. Your only option is to use a Canvas or a PIL image to draw the text, instead of a Label.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried this but I think you had already done this before,

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk

main=Tk()

photo=Image.open("Eujbx.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photo)

aa=Label(main,image=photo)
aa.pack(expand=True,fill=BOTH)

title=Label(aa,text="This app is to look for homework",bg='#9e87b9')
title.pack(pady=10)

new=Entry(aa,bg="#9e87b9")
new.pack()

Button(aa,bg="#9e87b9",text="Hlw").pack()

main.mainloop()
```

If you had not tried this yet then try it. It could help you.

Steps(Explanation):

> Using PIL to get the image,

> Then change image to ImageTk which we can use,

> Make Label which store the image and show in the background,

> pack that with expandable form and fill Both side(X and Y),

> Create the label and other stuff,

> put all of them inside the main Label which contain background image,

> give them background color of color of background image.